# How to move media and var directory to a volume instead of main server disk space?

Tags: magento2.4

I have a small server: 4 vcpu cores, 8 gb ram and 40 gb ssd. And i attached to it a volume that's 1TB in size (i know it is not enough in terms of cpu/ram but i will upgrade to a much better server soon).

Here is how it looks when i run `df -h`

```
root@ubuntu-edit:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            953M     0  953M   0% /dev
tmpfs           194M  776K  194M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        38G  1.8G   35G   5% /      <------------ server's ssd space
tmpfs           970M     0  970M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           970M     0  970M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15       61M  7.8M   53M  13% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb       1007G   77M  956G   1% /mnt/volume-edit <------- volume's space
tmpfs          194M     0  194M   0% /run/user/0
```

Question is: how do i move the `media`(including images) directory, `var` directory and all other directories that tend to get pretty big to the volume and upload images and make the caching directly to that new location instead of keeping everything on the main server?

Is that even a thing?

Comment: I would move the folders to the mounted drive and create symlinks from the ssd to the volume although I am not sure if this is supported in Magento2.

Comment: @paj Can you help me understand or point me towards some valid resources on how to actually work with this symlinks? Thank you :D